# iOS 15. Notification icon is wrong

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios15

In my app in the `Assets` I have an icon which is displayed on the notification banner when a push notification is arriving. It is marked as `iPhone Notification iOS 7-15 20 pt`. So the problem is simple: on iOS 15 this icon is not shown. The spotlight app icon is shown instead. On all the older versions everything is ok and the needed icon is shown. So how do I fix it?

Comment: any luck?? anybody??

Comment: @Md.Arif take a look at my answer. May be it can help you

Answer (score 1):

So this is how I resolved the issue. It's a very dirty hack of course, I'm far from stating it is even slightly good but I had no other choice. As the spotlight icon was shown on the notification banner I just put the needed image in place of the spotlight icon. I searched all over the system and failed to find any place where this spotlight icon is shown else. As far as I can see now it is shown only on the notification banner))) so, it is stupid and ugly but I failed to come up with anything else

Comment: I don't understand this. it doesn't make sense. Is this a bug? Or is it intentional? Anyway It helped.